# Measuring time in Julia and the behavior of function calling

Tags: time, timer, jupyter-notebook, julia

I have two questions and I would write them at the bottom of this article.

## Background

I measured time using [TimerOutputs.jl](https://github.com/KristofferC/TimerOutputs.jl) package and I found incomprehensible behavior.

I wrote the function named `f` and measured the following 4 sections:`whole in`,`i section`,`x section`,`whole out`.

The code and the result is following:

[input 1]

```
using TimerOutputs
const to = TimerOutput()

f = function()
    @timeit to "whole in" begin
        a = [];
    
        @timeit to "i section" begin
            for i in 1:1000
                push!(a,randn(5,5))
            end
        end
    
        @timeit to "x section" begin
            for x in 1:1000
                push!(a,randn(5,5) .+ x )
            end
        end
    end
end

@timeit to "whole out" f()

show(to)
```

[output 1]

```
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                 Time                   Allocations      
                         ──────────────────────   ───────────────────────
    Tot / % measured:         106ms / 95.8%           12.0MiB / 99.4%    

 Section         ncalls     time   %tot     avg     alloc   %tot      avg
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 whole out            1    102ms   100%   102ms   11.9MiB  100%   11.9MiB
   whole in           1    310μs  0.30%   310μs    878KiB  7.18%   878KiB
     x section        1    155μs  0.15%   155μs    579KiB  4.73%   579KiB
     i section        1    151μs  0.15%   151μs    298KiB  2.43%   298KiB
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

[input 2]

```
TimerOutputs.time(to["whole out"])/TimerOutputs.time(to["whole out"]["whole in"])
```

[output 2]

```
328.0928134063809
```

## Questions

Q1:

Why is the time for running `whole out` 328 times bigger than that for running `whole in`?

I guess this difference comes from the mechanics of how CPU and Memory behaves when a function is called, but I don't have any knowledge. I want to make it clear.

Q2:

I want to measure time for running `f` and use the result (output of `@timeit` for `whole out`) inside the `f`. How can I do this?

Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: A few comments: (1) to avoid measuring precompilation time, which as the answers mention is probably what you're seeing, you might rather use something like @benchmark from BenchmarkTools.jl. (2) if you care about performance to the degree that you care about timing things in detail, you probably ought not to be using `push!` if at all possible. Preallocate and fill in-place instead (or at the very least give `push!` a `sizehint!` to work with).

Answer (score 2):

**Q1**: You're likely timing the precompilation of `f`. Try to run `f` once before or reset the timer:

```
julia> reset_timer!(to) ;

julia> @timeit to "whole out" f()

julia> show(to)
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
                                 Time                   Allocations
                         ──────────────────────   ───────────────────────
    Tot / % measured:         4.02s / 0.02%           0.99MiB / 86.4%

 Section         ncalls     time   %tot     avg     alloc   %tot      avg
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 whole out            1    856μs   100%   856μs    879KiB  100%    879KiB
   whole in           1    842μs  98.4%   842μs    878KiB  100%    878KiB
     x section        1    515μs  60.2%   515μs    579KiB  65.8%   579KiB
     i section        1    321μs  37.6%   321μs    298KiB  33.9%   298KiB
 ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

**Q2**: I'm not sure what you mean. Maybe it would be best to ask that again in a separate question with corresponding copy-pastable code of what you've tried so far.